# jQueryで特定のattrを持つ要素の中からランダムに一つだけ表示にしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

以下のようにある部分までの想定はできているのですが、どうしても
「str」を持つ要素だけを取得、配列に代入する方法が分からず苦戦しています。

```js
function getCurrentImage(str) {
  /*
  * TODO : strを持つ要素を取得して配列に代入
  */
  var elm = [];

  //配列からランダムに値を取得
  var random = elm[Math.floor(Math.random() * elm.length)];

  //対象をdisplay:blockにする
  elm.random.css('display', 'block');
}

getCurrentImage('day');
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="a.jpg" data-role="day">
<img src="b.jpg" data-role="day">
<img src="c.jpg" data-role="day">
<img src="d.jpg" data-role="night">
<img src="e.jpg" data-role="night">
```

どなたか良い方法をご存知、もしくは似たような経験をお持ちの方のお力添えを願いたく投稿させていただきました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery で下記のようにして指定属性で要素を取得できます。
配列に(変換)する必要はないです。`.get`でインデックスを指定して要素を取り出せます。

```
function getCurrentImage(str) {
  var elm = $("img[data-role='" + str + "']");//指定属性の要素の取得
  //取得した要素からランダムに要素を取得
  var random = elm.get(Math.floor(Math.random() * elm.length));
  //対象をdisplay:blockにする
  $(random).css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: `.get()`のみでインデックス指定出来たんですね。そもそも`$('img')`で配列として（という認識であってますか？）取得できている事にも驚きです。
大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @kphex  `$(セレクタ)`のようにして取得した要素の集合はjQueryオブジェクトであって即配列というわけではありません（jQueryのオブジェクトとして他のAPIが適用できる）。オブジェクトの一部として内部的に要素の配列（あるいはノードリストのような配列のようなオブジェクト？）として保持されていたと思いますがそれは実装にかかわることなので、それを直接配列として取り出したりせずに`get`のようなAPIを使用します。